# Sort dictionary of type [String:any]

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter

Frankly speaking, When I try to do filtering for the dictionary with the following key and value pair ["deviceId":21,"geofenceId":34], it's order get changed randomly. But, As a matter of fact, I want to be in the same order the whole time. How to do that with the same [String:Any] type.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. You can create an array of the keys and sort that array any way you like. Maybe a dictionary isn't the right data structure...

Comment: It sounds like you'll be a lot happier if you mapped or wrapped that dictionary into a class or struct. Dictionaries are not supposed to be sorted, they are meant to be key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary collection is unordered, but you can sort the keys though

```
let myDict = ["geofenceId":34, "deviceId": 1]
let sortedKeys = myDict.keys.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
print(sortedKeys)
```

Now you can loop through the sorted keys and access the item from dictionary.

Comment: The thing is that, for the first time I I tried with it..But, the data type it has after getting converted is [(key: String, value: Any)], the fact of the matter is, I want the data type to be in [String:Any]. So I converted it to make this way using the below code. But it got happened to come in the same unordered way. So how to resolve it?.  For instance,           sortedKeys.forEach{
                params[$0.0] = $0.1
            }